# how can i test payable Dapp solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle

This is my code, a simple lottery contract, saves the address participants in the mapping, it is not finished but i want to test if i can receive the payment

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Lottery {

  uint lotteryFee = 0.1 ether;
  uint8 counter = 0;
  mapping (uint8 => address) participants;

  function participate() external payable returns(address) {
    require(msg.value == lotteryFee);
    counter = counter + 1;
    participants[counter] = msg.sender;
    return(participants[counter]);
  }

  function getBalance() public returns (uint) { 
    uint contractBalance = address(this).balance;
    return(contractBalance);
  }
}
```

and my test is this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Lottery.sol";

contract TestLottery1 {
  Lottery lottery = Lottery(DeployedAddresses.Lottery());
  //Testing the participate() function
  function testUserCanParticipate() public {
    address returnedId = lottery.participate();
    address expected = msg.sender;
    Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "You are participating");
  }
}
```

how or where i put the value i want to send to the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the initial balance first in your testing contract and the send the value to the function

```
contract TestLottery1 {
  uint public initialBalance = 1 ether;
  Lottery lottery = Lottery(DeployedAddresses.Lottery());

  //Testing the participate() function
  function testUserCanParticipate() public {
    address returnedId = lottery.participate.value(1)(); //here the value is in wei
    address expected = msg.sender;
    Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "You are participating");
  }
}
```